# Unclear why I'm getting a strange result when trying to add JSON features to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, leaflet

I'm working on a function in leaflet that changes the style `weight` of the most recent object in a JSON response. That's beside the point though, because I can't properly get the JSON objects into an array.

When I run `console.log(dates)` in order to see if they were pushed to the `dates` array I return this in the console. A bunch of empty arrays, amounting to the number of dates in the JSON response.

[image]

When I run `console.log(time)` to ensure I am in fact reaching the correct json feature I receive the dates (epoch format) as expected, but can not understand why they will not be pushed into the array `dates`. Any ideas?

[image]

**Function**

```
//most recent earthquake identifer

function mostRecent(time) {
    var dates=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
        dates.push(time[i])
    }
    console.log(dates)
return true
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// adds geojson feed of earthquakes from USGS url (must create a function to layer it on leaflet)

$.getJSON('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson', function(earthQuakes) {
    var points = L.geoJSON(earthQuakes, {
        filter: eqFilter,
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  // binds data in geosjon to a popup
            var eqDate = new Date(feature.properties.time); // converts epoch date
            layer.bindPopup(
                '<b>Location: </b>' + feature.properties.place + '<br>' +
                '<b>Magnitude: </b>' + feature.properties.mag + '<br>' +
                '<b>Depth: </b>' + feature.geometry.coordinates[2] + 'km' + '<br>' +
                '<b>Time: </b>' + eqDate.toGMTString() + '<br>' +
                '<br><center><a href=' + feature.properties.url + '>USGS Details</a></center>',
            )
        },
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){  // changes default icons to circles and styles accordingly
            return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: circleSize(feature.properties.mag),
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.mag),
                color: "#000",
                weight: mostRecent(feature.properties.time),
                opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
            });

        }
    }).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(points.getBounds()); // pans to points
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `dates` variable a global variable. You're actually resetting the `dates` array on every function call. Refactor it to something like this

```js
var dates = [];

function mostRecent(time) {
  dates.push(time);
  console.log(dates);
  return true
}
```

It should be working.

Comment: I did try that and receive one empty array via console.log(dates). coding can be so frustrating at times haha

Comment: I'm a little confused...How are each of  the dates pushed without a for loop? Thanks alot!

Comment: Actually the `feature.properties.time` returns a `number` not `array`, that's why it wasn't working. You can easily check it by using `console.log(typeof time)`, it returns number.

Comment: I am having trouble accessing each element. For some reason console.log(dates[0]) retrieves undefined. I'm not sure I understand why the typeof number would hinder it from being pushed into an array...sorry coming from python

Comment: You're getting undefined because the GET request is probably not completed and dates aren't pushed to the array. Try checking the length of array before invoking anything, like `if (dates.length !== 0) console.log(dates[0]) else console.log('Array isn\'t ready yet');`. Hope this helps.